# Backbone - Accessing Model defaults through Collection in a View

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

Ok thaht might not be too clear.

I passed a collection to my view. My collection has a Model, and the Model has defaults in an array. When I log the collection from the View it shows no length. But there are 4 defaults in my model. How can I get the default of my model to my view?

The call to view:

```
var menuLinks = new App.Collections.MenuLinks ;
var newView = new App.Views.Navbar({ collection: menuLinks }) ;
```

View:

```
App.Views.Navbar = Backbone.View.extend({

   initialize: function(){

   console.log(this.collection) ;
     //this.render() ;

   }

});
```

COllection:

```
App.Collections.MenuLinks = Backbone.Collection.extend({

model: App.Models.MenuLinks

});
```

Model:

```
App.Models.MenuLinks = Backbone.Model.extend({

//Default menus
defaults:[
    {
        name: 'Home',
        href: ''
    },
    {   name: 'Trips',
        href: '#trips'
    },
    {   name: 'Login',
        href: '#login'
    },
    {   name: 'LogoutOhYeah',
        href: '#logout'
    },
]

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

So... you simply want something like:

```
var collection = this.options.collection, defaults;
defaults = collection.length && collection.models[0].defaults ||{};
```